# How to implement Auto Power Up in Android like Motorola Atrix 2 Auto Shut down & Auto power up app?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Motorola Atirx2 has a built in feature like Auto Shutdown and Auto Power Up (Rerfer Image).
How to implement this app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not so straight forward to implement. Logically when you shutdown almost your device is dead but even then some BIOS will be running to maintain time and boot process. And once it get invoked it starts. So it is not only application associated but also kernel associated. So Motorola have entire control to handle all kernel side. So they doing it. But as a end developer it's not so straight forward. Instead better you take a look whether you can work out with Restart!